# Windows iot viewsonic touch screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, touchscreen, windows-10-iot-core

`Viewsonic-td2740,` I need to get it working on windows-iot.
I read that you can create your own cab files.

I have tried:

1. to connect to a windows PC and find the drives that are used and copy to Driver and Info files
2. to create a cab file and i keep getting errors

If you could let me know how to complete this i thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/build-your-image/CreateInstallPackage#create-a-driver-package) to build a package for the driver of `Viewsonic-td2740` and then install the package on the window iot device. But if there is any compatible issue with Viewsonic-td2740, i think you should contact with Viewsonic to support. You can see the compatible touchscreen in Windows IoT Core [Hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist).